# How to get gtk3 border with in Vala?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I have a GTK3 Window object in Vala and I need to get its Border struct:

http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Border

How to do it? This changed a lot in Gtk3. Thanks

Comment: What it is exactly you want to get ?

Comment: Was calculating mouse position and wanted to have this working with wider borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has one. Perhaps you want the `border-width` property?